# How to filter a table in SQL by a foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am making an website where bike repairs can be registered. It works, but now I am fine tuning. I have a MySQL database with a table called "Reparation", "Customer" and "bike"

In bike, there is a unique ID with the model, brand, and so on. In Customer, there are the customerID, Customer name, adress, and so on. In Reparation I can select a customer and a bike, so they are related, that's good too :).

When I select a customer in reparation, I want to see only his bikes. So, when the customer has two bikes, I want to select the customer and see the two bikes only (or the uniqueID'S from them).

Now I select a customer, and I see all the bikes of all the customers. How do I do this, in phpMyAdmin or PHP? Both are good, but better phpMyAdmin if possible..

Comment: Aaaand what did you try? where is your code? show us something to work on!

Comment: With an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: show us the structure of tables to help you better

Comment: Bear in mind you have a MySQL database, not a phpMyAdmin database. Your data is stored in MySQL, and phpMyAdmin is just a user-friendly way of accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since one Customer can have multiple Bikes, and one Bike belongs to one customer, you should store the CustomerID in your bike table ([1-to-many relationship](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561)).

```
Bike                                     Customer
  + bikeID                                 + customerID
  + bikeBrand                              + customerAddress
  ...                                      ...
  + customerID
```

And then, to select all the bikes belonging to a customer whose ID is X :

```
SELECT bikeID FROM Bike WHERE customerID = X;
```

Comment: Yes this worked. i hoped that i could just click&play in PHPMyAdmin, but it is a SQL query which i can execute in PHP.. Now i want to put the output into a dropdown list on my website.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent provided the table structure, we can only give you example:

So you can try something like:

`SELECT * FROM Reparation WHERE customer_id = selected_customer_id;`

Comment: It selects only the customer. You need to join it with `Reparation` and `Bike` table.